# Browser Specific "Override Hangers"

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, opera

I am working in Firefox (a standards compliant browser, right?), and my page looks fine in Google Chrome, and IE 9 (don't know about Safari), but a few aspects of my page go quirky in Opera. So, in IE 8 thru 6, I can use the `[if lte IE8]` tags, but is there anything similar for these "standards compliant" browsers (Opera in specific). And yes, I do have the latest version of Opera.

Comment: Conditional comments only apply to IE.

Comment: So there are no conditional comments or similar techniques for other browsers?

Comment: Not with only CSS. You could use JavaScript to sniff out browser features though.

Comment: I wondered... Thank you.

Comment: Btw, if you put that in answer form, in a few days if there are no better answers, I'll accept it. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional comments (e.g. [if lte IE8]) only apply to IE and to do any other kind of browser or feature detection you would need JavaScript.